# Combination of line and column chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for chart combination of line and column.

I have Rental and capital value data of multiple years for multiple cities,

Following data,

```
City: Mumbai, Pune 
Year: 2014, 2015
Rental value for Mumbai for each year respectively : [90,100]
Capital value for Mumbai for each year respectively:[6000,7000]
```

Required graph:
I want to plot chart with each city as x-axis and capital value with column chart for each year and rental value with line chart for each year.
Is it possible?

Referred url: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic
In this url, For january we have four columns(suppose for capital value), line chart(Rental value) should connect these columns only.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can combine a line series with a column easily. There is an example on the official website when those two series are combined - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo. See the fiddle on the website for the specific code.

Comment: In given example,line chart connects all elements on x-axis, my requirement    is to connect line chart for only specific values of each element on x-axis.

Comment: You can put null in places where should be the gap. http://jsfiddle.net/s2gb38ap/

Comment: i.e In given example, line chart should connect 3 columns for "Apples", so on for every x-axis element separate lint chart. Is it possible?

Comment: Create one series per column's group and specify x value for the points - http://jsfiddle.net/s2gb38ap/1/

Comment: column number can vary (in example 3 columns for "Apples", it could be 4,5,6...) as per filters applied, so while creating one series per column's group how to specify x value, so the respective point (of line chart) should come on exact column's position.   here: http://jsfiddle.net/s2gb38ap/1/   , for  3 columns x-axis values are set correctly so the line chart points belongs to each column.